# Reactjs filtering is not working when deselect value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using `ToggleButtonGroup` from React MUI. When user click on toggle buttons, I compared first letter from `stbNumber` value and filter out array. Filtering is working when I select toggle buttons but It's not working when I deselect the toggle buttons. Please help me, if I missed out anything.

```
const [filteredData, setFilteredData]: any = useState([]);
const [filterNumbers, setFilterNumbers]: any = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const filtered: any = channels.filter(({ stbNumber }: any) => {
    return filterNumbers.includes(stbNumber[0]);
  })

  if (filterNumbers.length > 0) {
    setFilteredData(filtered)
  }

}, [channels, filterNumbers])

const handleFilterNumbers = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, channelNumbers: string[]) => {
  setFilterNumbers(channelNumbers);
};

return (
<>
 <ToggleButtonGroup value={setFilterNumbers} onChange={handleFilterNumbers} sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
   <ToggleButton value="1">100 - 199</ToggleButton>
   <ToggleButton value="2">200 - 299</ToggleButton>
 </ToggleButtonGroup>
  <ChannelList content={filteredData} />
</>
)
```

```
const channels = [
  { name: "tv1", stbNumber: "101"},
  { name: "tv2", stbNumber: "102"},
  { name: "tv3", stbNumber: "201"},
  { name: "tv4", stbNumber: "202"},
  { name: "tv5", stbNumber: "300"},
];
```

Sample Image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key problem is that you need to handle the `else` case of `if(filterNumbers.length > 0)`. This will ensure removing any data if the filter is deselected:

```
if (filterNumbers.length > 0) {
  setFilteredData(filtered);
} else {
  setFilteredData([]);
}
```

Additionally I would **strongly suggest** making the following changes:

1. Proper TypeScripting:

```
type Channel = {
  name: string;
  stbNumber: string;
};

// Inside your component
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState<Channel[]>([]);
const [filterNumbers, setFilterNumbers] = useState<string[]>([]);
```

2. Removing unnecessary dependencies from `useEffect()` since mutating them **doesn't re-render** the component. These are called outer scope values and they aren't valid dependencies.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = channels.filter(({ stbNumber }) => {
      return filterNumbers.includes(stbNumber[0]);
    });

    if (filterNumbers.length > 0) {
      setFilteredData(filtered);
    } else {
      setFilteredData([]);
    }
  }, [filterNumbers]);  // 'channels' removed
```

3. In your example the `ToggleButtonGroup` didnt have a valid value. I assumed you meant:

```
    <ToggleButtonGroup
      value={filterNumbers} // instead of value={setFilterNumbers}
```

Your final component would look like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState<Channel[]>([]);
  const [filterNumbers, setFilterNumbers] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = channels.filter(({ stbNumber }) => {
      return filterNumbers.includes(stbNumber[0]);
    });

    if (filterNumbers.length > 0) {
      setFilteredData(filtered);
    } else {
      setFilteredData([]);
    }
  }, [filterNumbers]);

  const handleFilterNumbers = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    channelNumbers: string[]
  ) => {
    setFilterNumbers(channelNumbers);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ToggleButtonGroup
        value={filterNumbers}
        onChange={handleFilterNumbers}
        sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}
      >
        <ToggleButton value="1">100 - 199</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="2">200 - 299</ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
      <ChannelList content={filteredData} />
    </>
  );
}
```